Grafana Add Prometheus When You Only Have A /metrics Url
Im trying to add my Prometheus metrics to Grafana, but the problem is that we are only able to expose the /metrics  url for this.
When adding the Prometheus Data Source in Grafana, it is trying to hit /metrics/api/v1/label/<job name in Grafana> and since we only have /metrics this fails and returns a 404.
Is there any to simply provide the metrics urls in Grafana without the need for other endpoints?

I think you want to use Metrics Endpoint rather than the Prometheus Data Source. The Prometheus Data Source uses the Prometheus API (i.e. /api/v1/) endpoint.

Yea i tried this one too and wildly enough, it still hits the endpoint (i guess to determine the data format or something) and it fails @DazWilkin
